# How subscriptions are managed in PayTV securely?

Tags: key-exchange, digital-rights-management

- Since there are millions of subscriber for each operator in PayTV and each subscriber can subscribe to any of the package or individual channels, how operators transmit Entitlement management messages (EMMs) to each of the subscriber?
- How subscriptions are updated for each subscriber given subscribers can update their subscriptions at any time in the month?
- On which basis the grouping of subscribers is done?
- How are EMMs addressed to these groups?
- How operators manage all theses subscriptions within the bandwidth of just 3 Mbps?

Comment: I presume there are multiple schemes. Do you have any particular protocol / provider you can point at? Most of these schemes seem to be simple key wrapping schemes where particular keys to descramble a (set of) stream(s) are wrapped with the key of the subscriber; at least that's my information from ages ago.

Comment: Related http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41797/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-a-satellite-tv-signal-without-using-a-smart-card/41799#41799 . Probably searching for broadcast encryption would result in a few hits in your favorite search engine.

Comment: But if we send EMMs separately addressed to each subscriber, it consumes huge bandwidth since there are millions of subscribers (generally 10-20 million).
All those IEEE papers only tell about how to allocate keys to users. That too in generic words (as they should) which is difficult to relate to real scenario.

Comment: You can still encrypt the stream with the same session key. You then encrypt this session key with a subscriber specific key (possibly with a key or two in between). Once the stream is decrypted by an attacker using *whatever key* the stream is compromised anyway. Usually the stream is cut into pieces and each part encrypted with a separate key. Obviously retrieving the subscriber key breaks the scheme completely; the attacker would not have to even distribute the stream anymore (hence smart cards etc.).

Comment: I know this already. There is generally 3 to 4 level of keys in PayTV.

1. Actual content is scrambled using first level key a.k.a. control word, which is renewed generally every 10 sec.

2. Control words are encrypted with second level key a.k.a. service key. Encrypted CWs are sent inside Entitlement Control Messages.
Service Key is different for different services/channels. Service keys are updated generally every 1 hour.
3. Service keys are encrypted with third level key which can be a group key or directly user key. Encrypted service keys are sent inside Entitle management messages.

Comment: So again, what's the protocol and which part don't you understand?

Comment: I didn't understand how each subscriber is addressed for sending EMMs (within limited EMM bandwidth of 3Mbps) and how keys are updated by operator periodically?